# Azure CloudFile - "The specifed resource name contains invalid characters."

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to download a file from `Azure File Storage` to a local file and get this exception:

> "The specifed resource name contains invalid characters."

Here's the code:

```
if (_cloudFileShare.Exists())
{
      CloudFileDirectory rootDir = _cloudFileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference();    
      CloudFileDirectory tempDir = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference("temp");
      if (tempDir.Exists())
      {
        var file = tempDir.GetFileReference(saveFrom);
        file.DownloadToFile(saveTo, FileMode.Open);// OFFENDING LINE
      }
 }
```

The `saveTo` argument is a string and the value is something like this:

```
"C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpF2AD.tmp"
```

The `saveFrom` argument is something like this:

https://storageaccount.file.core.windows.net:443/fileshare/temp/tmpA2DA.tmp

I'm creating the argument using this function:

```
var saveTo = Path.GetTempFileName();
```

What am I doing wrong?  I don't have much experience with Azure.

Comment: What is the value of "saveFrom" variable?

Comment: @GauravMantri...please see my update, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your `saveFrom` variable. It should only contain the name of the file and not the whole URL. So if the file you're trying to download is `tmpA2DA.tmp`, your code should be:

```
var file = tempDir.GetFileReference("tmpA2DA.tmp");
```

Please make this change and try again. It should work.

Here's the complete code I used to test:

```
    static void FileDownloadTest()
    {
        var cred = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
        var account = new CloudStorageAccount(cred, true);
        var client = account.CreateCloudFileClient();
        var _cloudFileShare = client.GetShareReference("fileshare");
        if (_cloudFileShare.Exists())
        {
            CloudFileDirectory rootDir = _cloudFileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference();
            CloudFileDirectory tempDir = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference("temp");
            if (tempDir.Exists())
            {
                var saveTo = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
                var file = tempDir.GetFileReference("tmpA2DA.tmp");
                file.DownloadToFile(saveTo, FileMode.Open);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's because 'tempDir' has the path, right?  Thanks